# Why these async/await calls are not working properly?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await, stripe-payments

Help please!! During the execution of both await calls in `createPayment()` and in stripe API charges.create() the execution is made randomly not in order as expected. My code enters into `createPayment()` then goes back to `const {payment} = await createPayment(program, user, toUser, paymentToken);` then goes inside `createPayment()` again, it makes no sense!!!!

```
exports.subscribeToProgram = async function(req,res){
try {
    const {paymentToken, program} = req.body;
    const user = res.locals.user;

    //Find program to be subscribed
    const foundProgram = await Program.findOne({_id: program._id}).populate('user').exec();
    const toUser = foundProgram.user.id;
    if(toUser === user.id)
    {
        return res.status(422).send({errors: [{title: 'Invalid User!', detail: 'You can\'t subscribe to your own program!'}]})
    }

    // Create Payment
    // THIS PART IS NOT WORKING PROPERLY!!!! 
    const {payment} = await createPayment(program, user, toUser, paymentToken);
    const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
        amount: foundProgram.price * 100 * CUSTOMER_SHARE,
        currency: 'usd',
        description: 'Example charge',
        source: payment.tokenId,
    });

    //If payment was created successfully
    if(payment && charge)
    {
        //Create subscription
        //Save created subscription
        //Append a booking to bookings array
    }else{
        return res.status(422).send({errors: [{title: 'Payment declined!', detail: err }]})
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(422).send(err);  
}
}
```

**CreatePayment()**

```
async function createPayment(program, user, toUser, token){
//Get user from booking
const userToCharge  = user;

//Create customer from stripe serices
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    source: token.id,
    email: userToCharge.email
});

//If custome exist
if(customer)
{
    //Update user
    User.updateOne({_id: userToCharge.id}, {$set: {stripeCustomerId: customer.id}}, () => {});

    //Create Payment
    const payment = new Payment({
        fromUser: userToCharge,
        toUser, //Destructurize value
        fromStripeCustomerId: customer.id,
        program,
        tokenId: token.id,
        amount: program.price * 100 * CUSTOMER_SHARE // 80% of value if for 
    });

    //Save payment
    try 
    {
        const savedPayment = await payment.save();
        return {payment: savedPayment}
    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
        return {err: err.message};
    }
}else{
    return { err: 'Cannot process Payment!'}
}
```

}

Comment: Does `createPayment()` return a promise?  Does `stripe.charges.create()` return a promise?

Comment: `stripe.charges.create()` does returns a promise. `createPayment()` does not, it returns an object, however inside that function I am calling `await stripe.customer.create()` which returns a promise too

Comment: Add to @jfriend00, also it is possible you are calling `subscribeToProgram` multiple times without `await` in the parent function.

Comment: its better if you could share the code of parent call and `createPayment` function

Comment: Why are you using `await` with `createPayment()`?  `await` only does something useful when you call it on a promise.  If there are async things in `createPayment()` then you need to fix it to return a promise that is resolved when those async things are done.

Comment: It does make sense because something is calling `subscribeToProgram` and once execution reaches to call `createPayment`, it does not wait for it to finish because it is async and leaves the `subscribeToProgram` method. It enters `createPayment` again because `subscribeToProgram` method is called again by some code.

Comment: You need to study how `async` and `await` work.

Comment: I just edited the question with createPayment() function. I don't get Promises at all, asynchronous programming is just confusing me more and more.

Comment: Your issue with `createPayment()` is a dup of [How do I Return the Response from an Asynchronous Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323)

Comment: Read the post jfriend00 cited: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321) .  Then read [this](https://codeburst.io/javascript-learn-promises-f1eaa00c5461) and [this](https://codeburst.io/javascript-es-2017-learn-async-await-by-example-48acc58bad65).  Rinse and repeat as needed :)

Comment: @jfriend00 `createPayment` being `async` means it will implicitly return a Promise, one doesn't need to be explicitly returned. The issue looks like there is another async call (`User.updateOne`) that isn't being awaited.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I will try to add all of these, I also started reading the documentation posted by you @paulsm4 thanks for that. I will update the question as needed.

Comment: @James - The promise it returns needs to be resolved only when all the async operations inside the function are done.

Comment: @jfriend00 correct, the OP had just missed one await call inside `createPayment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues, both inside `createPayment`

1. You need to `await` the `User.updateOne` call as this is also asynchronous
2. In the event of no `customer` being found, you will still need to return an object, otherwise your destructuring will throw an error.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It is the third time I am programming asynchronous code so I am still getting used to it. I will update my code as you suggested. Thanks :)

Comment: @RodrigoVillalobos no problem, not sure if you edited `createPayment` or it was hidden by the overflow on the code but I see you *are* returning an object for no. 2.

Comment: You were right James, I was missing an await call inside createPayment, I also added an extra await call for charging the user inside the same function and it works perfectly! also Thanks to the resources  that @paulsm4 posted I was able to understand what was happening